# JQuery autocomplete not working with minLength 0 and custom styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery-ui autocomplete with Bootstrap custom styling.

I followed exact code given in example [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data):

However this doesnt seem to be working for `minLength: 0`, That is autocomplete doesnt appear when we click on input box or even when we type in a character or two. However if you backspace after typing and remove everything from input box, then the autocomplete options would appear. It is not searching any options either.

Demo: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohit1337/wa91nxmb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing a `label` property in your `source` array. That is the property against which jQuery autocomplete compares the user input. Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wa91nxmb/2/

Also, here's the part of code that changes:

```
 var coupons = [
    {
        coupon: 'abced',
        label: 'abced',
        desc: '50 OFF'
    },
    {
        coupon: 'GG_hijk',
        label: 'GG_hijk',
        desc: '75 OFF'
    },
];
```

Since you want to display all options when user focuses on the empty textbox, you can bind on the `focus` event and trigger the search through javascript.

```
 $("#coupon").focus(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete("search", $(this).val());
 });
```

Comment: Earlier I missed that you also need to view all options when the textbox is empty. Btw, you'd need the label property for jQuery to compare the user values against. Without that, when you type in 'ab' in textbox, you would not get matching option in the result.